# Multiply the outputs custom loss function

Tags: python, keras

So my question is, if I have something like:

```
model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = [y1,y2])

model.compile(loss = my_loss ...)
```

I have only seen `my_loss` as a dictionary of independent losses and, then, the final loss is defined as the sum of those. But, can I define in a multitask model a loss function that take all the predicted/true values and then I can multiply them (for instance)?

This is the loss I am trying to define:

```
def my_loss(y_true1, y_true2, y_pred1, y_pred2):
   final_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true1, y_pred1) + y_true1 * categorical_crossentropy(y_true2, y_pred2)
   return final_loss
```

Usually, your paramaters are `y_true, y_pred` in the loss function, where `y_pred` is either `y1` or `y2`. But now I need both to compute the loss, so how can I define this loss function and pass all the parameters to the function: `y_true1, y_true2, y_pred1, y_pred2`.

My current model that I want to change its loss:

```
x = Input(shape=(n, ))
shared = Dense(32)(x)
sub1 = Dense(16)(shared)
sub2 = Dense(16)(shared)
y1 = Dense(1)(sub1, activation='sigmoid')
y2 = Dense(4)(sub2, activation='softmax')

model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = [y1,y2])

model.compile(loss = ['binary_crossentropy', 'categorical_crossentropy'] ...) #THIS LINE I WANT TO CHANGE IT
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but I'll try.

The loss function must contain both the predicted and the actual data -- it's a way to measure the error between what your model is predicting and the true data.  However, the predicted and actual data do not need to be one-dimensional. You can make `y_pred` a tensor that contains both `y_pred1` and `y_pred2`.  Likewise, `y_true` can be a tensor that contains both `y_true1` and `y_true2`.

As far as I know, loss functions should return a single number. That's why loss functions often have a mean or a sum to add up all of the losses for individual data points.

Here's an example of mean square error that will work for more than 1D:

```
import keras.backend as K

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # this example is mean squared error
    # works if if y_pred and y_true are greater than 1D
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true))
```

Here's another example of a loss function that I think is closer to your question (although I cannot comment on whether or not it's a good loss function):

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # calculate mean(abs(y_pred1*y_pred2 - y_true1*ytrue2)) 
    # this will work for 2D inputs of y_pred and y_true
    return K.mean(K.abs(K.prod(y_pred, axis = 1) - K.prod(y_true, axis = 1)))
```

**Update:**

You can concatenate two outputs into a single tensor with `keras.layers.Concatenate`.  That way you can still have a loss function with only two arguments.

In the model you wrote above, the `y1` output shape is `(None, 1)` and the `y2` output shape is `(None, 4)`.  Here's an example of how you could write your model so that the output is a single tensor that concatenates `y1` and `y1` into a shape of `(None, 5)`:

```
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Concatenate

input_layer = Input(shape=(n, ))
shared = Dense(32)(input_layer)
sub1 = Dense(16)(shared)
sub2 = Dense(16)(shared)
y1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(sub1)
y2 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(sub2)
mergedOutput = Concatenate()([y1, y2])
```

Below, I show an example for how you could rewrite your loss function. I wasn't sure which of the 5 columns of the output to call `y_true1` vs. `y_true2`, so I guessed that `y_true1` was column 1 and `y_true2` was the remaining 4 columns. The same column structure would apply to `y_pred1` and `y_pred2`.

```
from keras import losses

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    final_loss = (losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0]) + 
                    y_true[:, 0] * 
                  losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true[:, 1:], y_pred[:,1:]))
    return final_loss
```

Finally, you can compile the model without any major changes from normal:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss)
```

Comment: Thanks Callin and sorry if it's not clear. I have tried to improve my question! :)

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow. If this answer or any other one (that may come later) solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, can you tell me where you're still stuck?

Comment: It looks for me that you have answered how to multiply the output of a uni-task model, but I would like to multiply the outputs of the different outputs of my model. I have changed the loss function in order that you see in a clearer way what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I see. I updated my answer in a way that I hope now answers your question.